# Why does ifelse return a vector of 1 if strict inequality is used?

Tags: r

I realized that my code is giving unanticipated results due to using *ifelse* with a strict inequality comparison:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = seq(-10,10)) %>%
  mutate( b = ifelse( (a<-3) , 1, 0) ) %>%
  mutate( c = ifelse( (a<=-3) , 1, 0) )
df
```

which gives

```
> df
# A tibble: 21 x 3
   a     b     c
 <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1   -10     1     1
2    -9     1     1
3    -8     1     1
4    -7     1     1
5    -6     1     1
6    -5     1     1
7    -4     1     1
8    -3     1     1
9    -2     1     0
10    -1     1     0
 ... with 11 more rows
```

b is a vector of ones, my understanding is that <- is perceived as an assignment instead of a comparison but if that is the case I don't understand why the code is quietly evaluated instead of spitting out an error.

Thanks for your help,

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the assignment operator `<-` instead of the comparison one `< -`. You just need to add one more space. Compare the two versions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(a = seq(-10,10)) %>%
  mutate(b_compare = ifelse(a < -3 , 1, 0),
         b_assign = ifelse(a<-3, 1, 0)) 
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#>        a b_compare b_assign
#>    <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1   -10         1        1
#>  2    -9         1        1
#>  3    -8         1        1
#>  4    -7         1        1
#>  5    -6         1        1
#>  6    -5         1        1
#>  7    -4         1        1
#>  8    -3         0        1
#>  9    -2         0        1
#> 10    -1         0        1
#> # … with 11 more rows
```

When you use the assignment operator `<-`, you are actually doing the equivalent of `ifelse(3, 1, 0)`, this is a strange logical statement, but unfortunately, `ifelse()` does not return an error, and instead consider it to be `TRUE` (check indeed `as.logical(3)`):

```r
ifelse(3, 1, 0)
#> [1] 1
```

If you were to use `dplyr::if_else()` instead, it would return an error:

```r
dplyr::if_else(3, 1, 0)
#> Error: `condition` must be a logical vector, not a double vector
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse()` is not supposed to throw an error here: `a <-3` is evaluated, returns 3 and every numeric `!=ˋ from 0 is converted to ˋTRUEˋ.

`ifelse` internally does an `if() ... else ...` and ˋif (3) ...` considers that 3 is TRUE.

In fact, if you'd have tried ˋifelse( (a<-"plop"), 1, 0)`, you'd get an error as "plop" can't be converted to logical.